# Inno Setup: Unknown identifier "IsWin64"

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to make an installer using Inno Setup but I am getting below error during compilation.

> **Compilation Error** : Unknown Identifier "IsWin64"

```pascal
if IsWin64 then
begin
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\Temp\iis.bat'),'', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end
  else
begin
  Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\Temp\iis32.bat'),'', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end
```

I am working on Windows 7 64-bit OS and using Inno Setup 5.0.8.

Comment: What version of Inno Setup are you using?

Comment: I am using version Inno 5.0.8

Answer (score 0):

[Inno Setup 5.0.8](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.0.8) is over **13 years old** (2005)!

So, I guess, you now know, what to do...

---

Though funnily, [`IsWin64` was added in the very next version, 5.1.0](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm#5.1.0), still over 13 years ago.